# Regarding formatting done in Xsl FOO

Tags: xml, xslt

I have got the solution to the problem, want to thank you all you guys since without your timely solutions and advise this was impossible to achieve and solve thanks a lot..!!

A solution to this problem have been achieved thanks a lot..!!

Comment: @Folks Please advise..!!

Comment: This is similar to your another question [Few modification in xsl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383676/few-modification-in-xsl/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this property `keep-with-next="always"

```
<fo:table-header>
   <fo:table-row keep-with-next="always">
         <fo:table-cell>
               <fo:block font-weight="bold"></fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
           <fo:table-cell>
              <fo:block text-align="left" space-after="4mm"
                  space-before="3mm" font-weight="bold">
                  <xsl:text>DEPARTMENT TOTALS</xsl:text>
               </fo:block>
           </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</fo:table-header>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,One more thing for my understanding please advise what this keep-with-next will do , and second thing as I will set this property for  DEPARTMENT TOTALS so do I need to set for other  renaming individuals also(SS SALES , CIGARETTE SALES, LIQUOR SALES,TOTAL FRONT END SALES), Please advise. or by setting in table header alone will also work.

Comment: I have updated my post please see in the second figure DEPARTMENT TOTALS is also coming along with  TOTAL FRONT END SALES which should not, Please advise I was trying to look it as it is being done on the very first page itself all the things , DEPARTMENT TOTALS (SS SALES , CIGARETTE SALES, LIQUOR SALES,TOTAL FRONT END SALES) should move to the next page.

Comment: keep-with-next always is for bind together rather than splitting two pages. use it in table-row.

Comment: so If my report increases from one page to second page or more, then what would happen please advise.

Comment: @Stivel..Could you also please look at the question at this url..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392683/regarding-changes-need-to-be-done-in-xsl