# Few modification in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have created the report that provides the department wise sales done in a particular day, It's design is being done in xsl as shown below..Please see department sales report...

[image]

The xsl used for that is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" extension-element-prefixes="set" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-width="21cm" page-height="29.7cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm">
           <fo:region-body margin-bottom="2cm" margin-top="4cm"/>
          <fo:region-after extent="2cm"/>
          <fo:region-before extent="4cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
              </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" initial-page-number="1">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" 
                               text-align="left" font-size="9pt"  >
               </fo:block>
          <fo:block font-size="9pt" text-align="end">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
              <fo:table-column column-width="9.5cm"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="9.5cm"/>
               <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell
                                        text-align="center">
                    <fo:block text-align="left">
                                            Run:
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(  DepartmentSalesReport/CurrentDate , 6, 2 )" />
                                        /
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(  DepartmentSalesReport/CurrentDate , 9, 2 )" />
                                        /
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(  DepartmentSalesReport/CurrentDate , 1, 4 )" />
                                        @
                                    <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/currentTime" />
                                        </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                   <fo:table-cell text-align="right">
                    <!--fo:block space-before="8mm">
                      <xsl:text>Keep this report for 6 months</xsl:text>
                    </fo:block-->
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell >
                    <fo:block space-before="8mm">Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="terminator"/></fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>

          </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
          <fo:block text-align-last="center" space-after="1.5cm">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
              <fo:table-column column-width="4cm"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="10cm"/>
               <fo:table-column column-width="2cm"/>
               <fo:table-column column-width="2cm"/>
              <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell  font-size="9pt">
                    <fo:block>Store Number:
                      <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/store_code"/>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                   <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                             <fo:block  text-align-last="center" font-size="14pt" font-weight="bold" space-after="1mm">
                                <fo:inline text-decoration="underline">Department Sales Report</fo:inline>
                               </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell text-align="right"   font-size="9pt">
                     <fo:block > 
                        <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/tradingday"/>   
                     </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell text-align="right" font-size="9pt">
                    <xsl:variable name="date"><xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/tradingdate"/></xsl:variable>
                    <fo:block> 
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($date,5,2)"/>/<xsl:value-of select="substring($date,7,2)"/>/<xsl:value-of select="substring($date,1,4)"/>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
          <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
              <fo:table-column column-width="19cm"/>
          <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                   <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                                      <fo:block text-align-last="center" font-size="9pt" >
                                        Summary of Sales by department, only those
                                            departments with activity (Sales,
                                            refunds, voids) will appear on this
                                            report.Use this report to monitor sales in
                                            key departments and make merchandising
                                            decisions as needed.
                          </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
          </fo:block>
          <fo:block font-size="9pt" >
           <fo:table table-layout="fixed" >
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.8cm" 
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9"> <fo:block color="black"
                        space-before.optimum="-8pt">
                        <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" 
                               text-align="left" font-size="9pt"  />

                    </fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row font-weight="bold">
                                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="left"><xsl:text>-------------------------Department-------------------</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>Net Sales</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>Qty</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>% of Sales</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>--------Void--------</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>-------Return-------</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>        
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-row font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:text>Description</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Qty</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Amount</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Qty</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Amount</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row >
                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9" > <fo:block color="black"
                        space-before.optimum="-8pt">

                    </fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>

                            </fo:table-body>
                            </fo:table>
          </fo:block>
          <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" 
                               text-align="left" font-size="9pt"  />



     </fo:static-content>


        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <xsl:variable name="storeSales" select="sum(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentDesc/netSales)"/>
        <br/>
          <!--          <fo:block font-size="9pt" space-after="3mm" break-before="page">-->
            <xsl:for-each select="DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentDesc">
                    <fo:block font-size="9pt" space-after="1mm">
                    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" >
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.8cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <xsl:variable name="levelNo"><xsl:value-of select="levelNbr"/></xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name="levelCheck"><xsl:value-of select="level"/></xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:if test="$levelCheck!=''">
                                    <xsl:if test="$levelNo='2'">
                                    <fo:table-row>  
                                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9">
                                    <fo:block>
                                           <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                                    </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:if>
                     <fo:table-row >
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="level"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>

                                        <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="$levelNo!='2'">
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="prgpName"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                    ***DEPT TOTAL*** </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(netSales,'0.00')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(prodCount,'0')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>


                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <xsl:variable name="salesPercentage"><xsl:value-of select="format-number((netSales div $storeSales)*100, '###,##0')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$salesPercentage='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$salesPercentage!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$salesPercentage"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(postVoidQuantity,'0')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(postVoidAmount,'0.00')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(returnQuantity,'0')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(returnAmount,'0.00')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                        <xsl:if test="$levelNo='2'">
                                    <fo:table-row>  
                                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9">
                                    <fo:block>
                                           <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                                    </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:if>
                    </fo:table-body>

                  </fo:table>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" text-align="left"
                font-size="9pt" space-before="3mm" />
            <fo:block font-size="9pt" space-after="4mm">

                <fo:table>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="1.5cm" />
                    <fo:table-column column-width="4.5cm" />
                    <fo:table-column column-width="3.3cm" />

                    <fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold"></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block text-align="left" space-after="4mm"
                                    space-before="3mm" font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>DEPARTMENT TOTALS</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>

                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-header>

                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>SS SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right">
                                    <xsl:variable name="ssSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/ssSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$ssSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$ssSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$ssSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>CIGARETTE SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block text-align="right" font-weight="bold">
                                <xsl:variable name="cigeratteSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/cigeratteSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$cigeratteSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$cigeratteSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$cigeratteSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block space-after="1.5mm" font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>LIQUOR SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right"
                                    space-after="4mm">
                                    <xsl:variable name="liquorSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/liquorSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$liquorSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$liquorSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$liquorSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" space-after="8mm">
                                    <xsl:text>TOTAL FRONT END SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right"
                                    space-after="4mm">
                                    <xsl:variable name="totalSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/totalSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$totalSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$totalSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$totalSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>

                    </fo:table-body>

                </fo:table>

            </fo:block> 



              <fo:block space-before="5mm" text-align="center" font-size="9pt" font-weight="bold" id="terminator">
                 <xsl:text></xsl:text>
          </fo:block>

        </fo:flow>

      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the xml is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report Name="DepartmentSalesReport" Title="Department Sales Report"
    Description="Department Sales Report" Version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <InitParam Name="tradingdate" Type="java.lang.String" />
      <InitParam Name="tradingday" Type="java.lang.String" />
      <ReportBand BandType="HeaderBand" Name="DepartmentSalesReportBand">
        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="OutletSQL">
        <DataField Name="store_code" Type="Data" FieldName="ORGU_CODE" />
        </ReportElement>
        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="InitParams">
        <DataField Name="tradingdate" Type="Data" FieldName="tradingdate" />
        </ReportElement>
        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="InitParams">
        <DataField Name="tradingday" Type="Data" FieldName="tradingday" />
        </ReportElement>
    </ReportBand>
    <ReportBand BandType="DetailBand" Name="Terminal">
        <ReportElement Type="Detail" Name="DepartmentDesc" DataSource="DataSql">
            <DataField Name="level" Type="Data" FieldName="LEVEL"/>
            <DataField Name="levelNbr" Type="Data" FieldName="LEVELNBR"/>
            <DataField Name="prgpName" Type="Data" FieldName="PRGP_NAME"/>
            <DataField Name="prodCount" Type="Data" FieldName="PROD_COUNT"/>
            <DataField Name="netSales" Type="Data" FieldName="NET_SALES"/>
            <DataField Name="postVoidQuantity" Type="Data" FieldName="POST_VOID_QUANTITY"/>
            <DataField Name="postVoidAmount" Type="Data" FieldName="POST_VOID_AMOUNT"/>
            <DataField Name="returnQuantity" Type="Data" FieldName="RETURN_QUANTITY"/>
            <DataField Name="returnAmount" Type="Data" FieldName="RETURN_AMOUNT"/>  

        </ReportElement>
        <ReportElement Type="Detail" Name="DepartmentTotals" DataSource="TotalsDataSql" MaxResults="1">
            <DataField Name="ssSales" Type="Data" FieldName="LINE_NUM_50"/>
            <DataField Name="cigeratteSales" Type="Data" FieldName="LINE_NUM_30"/>
            <DataField Name="liquorSales" Type="Data" FieldName="LINE_NUM_60"/>
            <DataField Name="totalSales" Type="Data" FieldName="TOTAL_FRONT_END_SALES"/>
        </ReportElement>

        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="DateSQL">
            <DataField Name="CurrentDate" Type="Data" FieldName="1" />
            <DataField Name="currentTime" Type="Data" FieldName="2" />
        </ReportElement>
    </ReportBand>
    <DataSource
        Type="walgreens.pos.maintenance.eod.CurrentDepartmentSalesReportDataSource"
        Name="DataSql"
        Statement="">
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource
        Type="walgreens.pos.maintenance.eod.DepartmentTotalsReportDataSource"
        Name="TotalsDataSql"
        Statement="">
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource
        Type="com.pcmsgroup.v21.star.framework.application.reports.SpringReadOnlySQLStatement"
        Name="OutletSQL"
        Statement="select ORGU_CODE,OUTL_TRADE_DATE from outlet,org_unit where outlet.OUTL_ID = org_unit.OUTL_ID">
    </DataSource>

    <DataSource
        Type="com.pcmsgroup.v21.star.framework.application.reports.SpringReadOnlySQLStatement"
        Name="DateSQL"
        Statement="SELECT current date,current time FROM sysibm.sysdummy1">
    </DataSource>

</Report>
```

Now the problem come when the report is increased from one page to second page or more as shown below the heading department totals also get printed on the next page which should not as shown below..

[image: the image 2]
Please advise what changes need to be done in xsl for this so that it should not come in second page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give page break. Please refer few examples here how to [Use XSL-FO for page breaks and tables](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tippgbk/index.html)

Can you try this :

```
<fo:block keep-with-next="always" text-align="left" space-after="4mm"
                                space-before="3mm" font-weight="bold">
     <xsl:text>DEPARTMENT TOTALS</xsl:text>
</fo:block>
```

this will keep table in single page.

Comment: @Stivel..thanks a lot, could you also suggest in this report where I need to do that,I mean in xsl, where this tag need to be put.

Comment: yeah it works thanks a lot, I got it..thanks from the bottom of my heart.!

Comment: could you also please look at another question of mine at the following url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374831/regarding-formatting-done-in-xsl-foo

Comment: keeping the table in single page means what, as it not cleared to me , and if my report get expanded..!!

Comment: keep table in single page means department total fo:table will be transformed in a single page. If enough space not available in a page, a page break will be given.

Comment: ok I will try this , what I understood is that if enough space is not given as what happened in the pic as shown above then a seprate page will be come in picture and all these ((DEPARTMENT TOTALS,SS SALES ,CIGRARETTE SALES, LIQUOR SALES,TOTAL FRONT END SALES) will move to next page but if space is there then they will be on very first page itself

Comment: @user1800852 Yes absolutely. Also ask questions with simple example. here you gave lot then it wont get more attention

Comment: Also please let me know for my knowledge what would happen if I put this keep with always with the renaming blocks of (SS SALES , CIGARETTE SALES, LIQUOR SALES,TOTAL FRONT END SALES) also individually..!

Comment: keep totals in single table.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..Ultimately what I was trying if the report end in a single page as shown in first image then it is perfect but if report get expanded due to more entries in it to second page or third page also..then my entries of ((DEPARTMENT TOTALS,SS SALES , CIGARETTE SALES, LIQUOR SALES,TOTAL FRONT END SALES)  should also come at last as shown in first page nothing in terms of formatting should get disturbed

Comment: @Stivel..Could you also please look at the question at this url..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392683/regarding-changes-need-to-be-done-in-xsl