# Avoiding the second page when first page is sufficient in xsl itself

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have got the solution to the problem, want to thank you all you guys since without your timely solutions and advise this was impossible to achieve and solve thanks a lot..!!

A solution to this problem have been achieved thanks a lot..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your problem keep all the following in single table and add it in table header. With refer to your xsl, everything treated as separate table.

```
 Store Number : 59998
                      Department Sales Report 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 xxxx                xxxx                                       Amount   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So that table header wont repeat if table body has no content.

Comment: could you please post the updated xsl by making modification in my xsl itself that will make understanding more clear..!Thanks

Comment: Bro mine concern was with the whole page the whole second page should not come if the first page fulfill the demand but if the first page is not sufficient as entries are more then second page should come in picture.

Comment: Yes, FOP will take care of it. if table rows exceeds, it will put it next page along with header.

Comment: Thanks bro but is there any other way also to achieve the same thing as I don't want to disturb the existing xsl design..!Thanks

Comment: If possible then please update my existing xsl also it will be a great help.!Thanks in advance